# PrimeNG PickList onMove and onMoveAll event handlers

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG PickList (5.0.0-rc0) for my Angular 5 application. My problem is that `onMoveToTarget` and `onMoveAllToTarget` get called simultaneously which I do not think it shouldnt behave like that. I use the PickList to dynamically add `FormControl` to my `Form` based on what is/are picked.

Use case:

```
onMoveToTargetHandler(event) {
  if (!this.moveAllToTarget) {
    this.form.addControl(event.items[0].slug, this._formBuilder.group({//some model that matches the control added}))
  }
}

onMoveAllToTargetHandler(event) {
  this.moveAllToTarget = true;
  let itemsProcessed = 0;
  event.items.forEach(item => {
   this.form.addControl(item.slug, this._formBuilder.group({//some model that matches the control added}));
   itemsProcessed++;
  });
  if (itemsProcessed === event.items.length) {
   this.moveAllToTarget = false;
  }
}
```

These two methods get called like almost simultaneously which causes me to have duplicated `FormControls` in my form.

Is there a way to get around this? I thought I'd ask here before submitting an issue to PrimeNG Github.

Comment: Maybe you should asked directly on their [forum](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewforum.php?f=35&sid=45e34922772fa61d6741489375083cde) ?

Comment: I did right after I posted this. Unfortunately, no answer yet

Comment: Had to modify the PickListModule for the moment to get around this.

Comment: Can you update how you got around this? It's still an issue in 2021

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try event.preventDefault()  on the first event so it will not spread to other events? If it doesn´t work, you may use a conditional to look the size of the items collection and then only one of them will render your form (even a mix of that)